# Trying to trick macOS software to run on High Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-high-sierra, method-swizzling

So I have some software that has begun to stop working now that I've updated to High Sierra. There has been no new version of the software released so I can't get a new supported version.

What I am wanting to do is find out whether or not the message that shows up saying that 10.13.4 is unsupported is, indeed, correct, or if it was just some arbitrary value the developer came up with. I guess it's more of a POC/ play around more than anything.

So, FYI, I am an iOS developer with a fairly good grasp on Objective-C and concepts such as method swizzling, which might be useful for tricking version checks into thinking the OS version is 10.12.x and to then unswizzle after launch.

I'm aware that it's possible to change the SystemVersion.plist, but as that would require disabling the system integrity protection, I'd really like to avoid this route if at all possible.

Any thoughts or suggested solutions would be appreciated. I'm aware that this system version check may be there for a legitimate functionality limitation of some sort, but I'm just too curious.

Comment: Is this some 3rd party application you've downloaded as a binary or is this something you have the source code for?

Comment: System integrity protection shouldn't prevent changes to third-party apps, or even older Apple apps.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The SIP disabling would be to edit the SystemVersion.plist file, not to allow it to open

Comment: @rmaddy It's a 3rd party application with no source code, sadly